# Need alternate solution for Microsoft SQL query

Tags: sql-server

I have the following table:

```
D1      D2      D3      D4      Proc_DtTm
716.90  NULL    NULL    NULL    2015-09-01 11:16:32.000
716.90  NULL    NULL    NULL    2015-09-01 13:59:26.000
716.90  NULL    NULL    NULL    2015-09-01 14:53:42.000
716.90  263.9   NULL    NULL    2015-09-16 10:47:40.000
716.90  263.9   NULL    NULL    2015-09-16 10:51:34.000
716.90  NULL    NULL    NULL    2015-09-16 10:54:42.000
716.90  NULL    NULL    NULL    2015-09-16 10:55:56.000
716.90  573.3   263.9   NULL    2015-09-16 10:56:09.000
716.90  573.3   263.9   NULL    2015-09-16 10:56:40.000
```

My requirements are this:

1. I need to return a comma-separated string of all the unique, non-null values from columns D1 through D4.
2. The value that is in column D1 on the first record when ordered by Proc_DtTm has to show up as the first value in the comma-separated string that is returned.
3. All other values can show up in any order.

Example: The above table should return the string '716.90,263.9,573.3'.

To solve this I currently have a really convoluted function that uses a cursor to loop through each record and write some stuff to temporary variables. I was in a rush to get a solution until I could revisit and make this efficient. Can anyone offer some suggestion on how to get my required return value without using a cursor based solution?

Comment: Can you please post your own attempt of code, then we can help you.

Comment: Yes there are better ways to do this than a cursor. Here is an excellent article about the XML trick to generate comma delimited lists. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/comma+separated+list/71700/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this construction but it looks completely ugly.

```
WITH firstD1 AS (
    SELECT TOP 1 D1 FROM yourTable WHERE D1 IS NOT NULL ORDER BY Proc_DtTm
),
other AS (
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT D1  FROM yourTable WHERE D1 IS NOT NULL
        UNION 
        SELECT DISTINCT D2  FROM yourTable WHERE D2 IS NOT NULL
        UNION 
        SELECT DISTINCT D3  FROM yourTable WHERE D3 IS NOT NULL
        UNION 
        SELECT DISTINCT D4  FROM yourTable WHERE D4 IS NOT NULL
    )
    EXCEPT 
    SELECT D1 FROM firstD1
)
select (select DISTINCT STUFF((SELECT  ',' + CAST(D1 as varchar(100)) 
    FROM firstD1
    ORDER BY D1
    FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') as p1
FROM firstD1) 
+ 
(select DISTINCT STUFF((SELECT  ',' + CAST(D1 as varchar(100)) 
    FROM other
    FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 0, '') as p2
FROM other)
```

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, I was not aware of the EXCEPT clause. I was working on something very similar with the UNIONs and could not get the return order correct. I think this will work out nicely.